# Custom router gives me "Front controller reached 100 router match iterations" when matches 404

Tags: magento2, router

I created a custom router

this is my di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Custom\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">40</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

This is the block match function:

```
public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        if(strpos($identifier, 'search') !== false) {

            $request->setModuleName('catalogsearch')->setControllerName('result')->setActionName('index');
        } else {
            //There is no match
            return;
        }

        /*
         * We have match and now we will forward action
         */
        return $this->actionFactory->create(
                        'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward', ['request' => $request]
        );
    }
```

Everything is fine till I got an error "Front controller reached 100 router match iterations" everytime I go to a 404 page.

Comment: what is the url of your 404 page ?

Comment: cms/noroute/index this is working, but when I get to example.com/any-inexistent-path, the error takes place

Answer (score 0):

try compile and flush cache

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
 bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: not working, already done

Comment: Try dump data in your condition "strpos($identifier, 'search')" I think it has problem in here

Comment: you mean to print the identifier value?

Answer (score 0):

Set return null in your else condition :

```
public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        if(strpos($identifier, 'search') !== false) {

            $request->setModuleName('catalogsearch')->setControllerName('result')->setActionName('index');
        } else {
            //There is no match
            return null;
        }

        /*
         * We have match and now we will forward action
         */
        return $this->actionFactory->create(
                        'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward', ['request' => $request]
        );
    }
```

Comment: not working... still gives me that error